# Intel D2700DC won't boot without display connected

Tags: boot, integrated-graphics, mini-itx

I have assembled a PC based on the [Intel D2700DC mini-ITX motherboard](http://ark.intel.com/products/56456/Intel-Desktop-Board-D2700DC?wapkw=d2700dc) to use it as headless server. I was able to install Fedora 17 Linux on it, and it worked fine until I disconnected display.

It still works perfectly if display disconnected after it booted, but won't start unless display is connected.

I have updated BIOS to the latest revision, turned EFI boot on and off, juggled video settings but that had no effect.

Initially, I thought it was a GRUB2 loader problem, so I used /etc/default/grub from [this thread](http://archlinux.org.ru/forum/post/19897/) and regenerated grub config, but that had no effect.
It also behaves same (boots with display, doesn't without it) with live usb stick with MS-DOS I have used to update BIOS.

Is there any way to make it boot without display connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that I had to disable IGD as well as beep warning on the "video device not present in BIOS". 
If you will ever need to enable it back, you should switch the on-board jumper to put BIOS into the Maintenance Mode. Integrated Graphics Device will be used by default in the Maintenance Mode.

**UPDATE:**

Adding `vmalloc=256MB video=LVDS-1:d` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and regenerating GRUB config (via `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`) solves the issue without need to disable IGD